# How to deploy angular application to client URL

Tags: angular, deployment, hosting, web-deployment, web-hosting

So a general question here but any advice would help. Let’s say I see there is a website of a dance studio and I want to rebuild it with angular and give the product to them. They already have a site url, what exactly would I need from them to get my product hosted on their pre existing url?

Comment: You need access to their server where the project is hosted. If it is on AWS then you will need a file for accessing their server.

Comment: Find the owner of the website domain, modify the DNS records by updating the A-HOST record to point to the IP address of your server, modify the C-NAME record to resolve to an alias sub-domain (if necessary). All you're doing here is pointing your domain URL to another server. Changes to DNS records will automatically propagate throughout the internet probably over the course of an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your angular app should be located on http://example.com/your_subfolder/ 
You can use

```
ng build --base-href "/your_subfolder/" --prod
```

to get /dist folder.

Then put /dist folder in your subfolder on the production server. 
On the server side all the requests except assets urls should be redirected to index.html